# already looged in instagram but not showing my basic details

Tags: php, instagram

```
<?php
//require 'db.php';
require 'instagram.class.php';
require 'instagram.config.php';

// Receive OAuth code parameter
 $code = $_GET['code'];




// Check whether the user has granted access
if (true === isset($code)) {

  // Receive OAuth token object
 $data = $instagram->getOAuthToken($code );
  // Take a look at the API response

if(empty($data->user->username))
{
echo "1";

}
else
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['userdetails']=$data;
    echo $user=$data->user->username;
echo    $fullname=$data->user->full_name;
echo    $bio=$data->user->bio;
echo    $website=$data->user->website;
echo    $id=$data->user->id;
echo    $token=$data->access_token;


}
} 
else 
{
// Check whether an error occurred
if (true === isset($_GET['error'])) 
{
    echo 'An error occurred: '.$_GET['error_description'];
}

}
?>
```

I am using PHP language . I have got the client id and client secret and I have inserted both the values + callback URL in the config file . My first page is my login page , when i clicked on the login page it will redirect me to this page only . In the code , I am getting the code and if the $data is empty ECHO  1  otherwise show all my details .
But when I clicked on the login button , it only shows me 1 but I am logged in in instagram